# UITextField does not receive text changes

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, iphone-3gs

we have a simple `UITextField` which lies on a second `UIWindow`. Touching it will correctly make it the first responder and a keyboard will be shown. However, no touched key, but the backspace, fires the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. Every other `UITextFieldDelegate` method is being correctly fired.
The textfield is created in an Interface Builder and it is not subclassed. Nothing seem to be stealing a first responder.

The bug occurs only on an iPhone 3GS, iOS 6.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, only the key window does get the changes from a first responder. It is as simple as to call `makeKeyWindow` on the appropriate window.

From the documentation:

```
Makes the receiver the main window.
```

Comment: Still not sure why this was an issue for iOS 6 only. 3GS seems to not be as relevant here, since we don't have any other phone with iOS 6. Perhaps an unfortunate bug on Apple side?